Using regex after removing HTML elements from a string
I'm trying to remove all HTML elements from an article and adding a highlight class at the end to highlight the search word. Unfortunately, this regex doesn't seem to work as expected. According to this post, a dynamic regex should be passed as a new RegExp().
const article = "some article content";

const format = (query, data) => {
    // remove all html elements
    const output =
      data.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gi, "").length > 400
        ? data.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gi, "").slice(0, 400) + "..."
        : data.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gi, "");

        //regex
    const highlight = new RegExp(String.raw`/${query}/`, "gi");

    // add highlight 
    return output.replace(
      highlight,
      `<span className="highlight">${query}</span>`
    );
  };

HTML:
<p className="paragraph--s">{format(searchTag, article)}</p>


Please [edit] your question to include the relevant html and form a complete [mre]. When/how are you calling format()?

@mykaf, thank you. I've made the adjustments.

The function takes two parameters: text, which is the text you want to search, and words, an array of words you want to highlight. It can handle multiple words in the text.


function highlightWords(text, words) {
    let output = text;
    words.forEach(word => {
        const regex = new RegExp(word, 'gi');
        output = output.replace(regex, '<strong>$&</strong>');
    });
    output = output.substring(0, 300); // Limit output to 300 characters, if needed
    return output;
}

function highlightText() {
    const text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    const searchWordsInput = document.getElementById('searchWords').value;
    const searchWords = searchWordsInput.split(',').map(word => word.trim());

    const highlightedText = highlightWords(text, searchWords);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = highlightedText;
}
strong {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#result {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
<label for="text">Text to Search:</label><br />
<textarea id="text" rows="5" cols="50">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</textarea>
<br>
<label for="searchWords">Words to Highlight (comma-separated):</label><br />
<input type="text" id="searchWords" value="fox, dog" placeholder="Enter words to highlight">
<br><br />
<button onclick="highlightText()">Highlight Words</button>

<span id="result"></span>



I originally posted PHP code not realizing you needed JavaScript. Here's translation.

hint: OP didn't mention PHP and neither tagged it so. How is this supposed to address his issue?

@LelioFaieta Thank you for letting me know. I was so focused on idea itself, completely ignored the language.

This function works without a loop. The key was to remove the backslashes from the regex and save each step in a separate variable.
const highlight = (search, data) => {
if (!search) return data;

const regex = new RegExp(String.raw`${search}`, "gi");

const output = data.replace(regex, `<span className="highlight">$&</span>`);

return output;
};

